# Substructural logic and the Continuum

Tags: logic

The SEP article on [change and inconsistency](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/change/#IncMot) goes over a theory of continuous motion that involves true contradictions. So arguably, the dialethic/paraconsistent Continuum is one way to logically frame the question of the Continuum's nature. For intuitionistic logic, the dual paracomplete moment of picturing the Continuum is covered [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/#TheCon).

Can we form a different question about the logical structure/character of the Continuum with reference to [substructural logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/)? So far, I have in mind something to the effect that we take a set of proximal real-valued points *p* and *q* and say that the translation

> (*p*1, *p*2, *p*3 ... ⊢ *q*) ↔ (*p*1 ⊢ (*p*2, *p*3, ...) → *q*)

is affected by the nature of these points' real-numerical proximity. Perhaps we might say that the translation is "true for" the Continuum, to express how its points/segments are connected, but on the prior (discrete?) level of representation, the translation is *not* "accurate." Or there are alternations over the usual translation that capture our sense of the connectedness of the Continuum better, and in turn reflect upon paraconsistent and paracomplete pictures of the Continuum. (Offhand, not knowing analysis very well at all, I am tempted to ask if *p*1 as described is anything like a "least upper bound" phenomenon.)

**Alternatively:** even if the Continuum is not profitably describable in terms of the question of substructural logic, is it possible to define sets whose natures involve variations on the question? I've heard about an [axiom of adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_adjunction), for example.